# Is it possible to query two tables from two separate databases in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to do something similar to following:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 " +
                             "WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id_table1 " +
                             "GROUP BY Table1.data1", null);
```

Is it possible to do the same using tables present over two different databases?

Comment: Why do you need two different databases...? And I do not believe that is possible.

Comment: @TronicZomB: Trying to write a _sync manager_ which will sync few columns of one database to another. Both the databases are maintained by 2 separate apps. Suggestion on any other better approach is also welcomed !!

Answer (score 4):

Just [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the other database first:

```
db.execSQL("ATTACH '/path/to/other.db' AS otherDB");
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1, otherDB.Table2 " +
            "WHERE Table1.id = otherDB.Table2.id_table1 " +
            "GROUP BY Table1.data1", null);
```

Comment: How is it possible to get the physical path of db of other application? I basically need to attach mediastore db to my local app db. But, on the device how would I get the path of mediastore db in android?

Comment: Android does not allow you to access other apps' data directly.